# Where is the actual documentation for highlight js / CKeditor theme values?

Tags: ckeditor, highlight.js

whether it be ckeditor themes, or codesnippet themes, where are the actual string values to pass as arguments to the config options? I'm having trouble finding the actual string values, or something pointing to the convention/pattern the value follows.

The ckeditor documentation is huge, and the links send you around in circles, referring you to generic documentation pages, but either the actual string values for possible arguments are not available.

the one example for plugins follows all lower case, no separation between words.
the highlight js themes that ckeditor requires seems to be snake case, but some are inconsistent and not working.

For instance, I'm looking to find values for

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  skin: 'kama',
  codeSnippet_theme:'tomorrow_night_dark'
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Don't blame CKEditor for poor Highlight.js documentation and inconsistent themes naming.

Comment: Question: the link I found are hosted by ckeditor, so are they not uniformitizing the file names as is in order to respect the way highlight js named them? I can't seem to find the files hosted by highlight js if it exists, so it would seem ckeditor could uniformitize them if they wanted to. Anyhow, I think a link to that page, with a short blurb telling people to use the file name without the path and suffix will help ppl and make the docs more thorough too.

Comment: i had a bad attitude because i was frustrated. ppl put in a lot of work, and i'm reaping the benefits so i really have nothing to complain about.

Answer (score 1):

http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/full-all/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/styles/

A link to to this in the ckeditor documentation would help, with a short liner saying to copy the file name excluding the paths and the file type suffixes.

reference the file name without the `.css` suffix to get the correct string format for the codeSnippet_theme,

the files are named inconsistently.

you might think you need
`'atelier_forest_dark'`, since `'school_book'` works, but it's actually 
`'atelier-forest.dark'`
It's also
`'tomorrow-night-bright'`
`hybrid`, which is available from the demos is not available from this list of CDN files hosted by ckeditor.